# limit number of record

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I use spring boot with spring data jdbc.

I search to get x number of record

In a interface I have

```
@Query("select u from user where status=1");
List<User> findUser();
```

Is it possible in spring data jdbc?

Comment: there is an existing [Baeldung page](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-limit-query-results) on this which may help you

Comment: @PaulBenn that page is about Spring Data JPA, the question is about Spring Data JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no build in mechanism to do that, so you can't just add a `Pageable` as an argument to achieve this.

But you can incorporate the limit in the query.
Note that the syntax varies between databases.
The following example should work for MySql

```java
@Query("select u from user where status=1 ORDER BY u LIMIT :rows)
List<User> findUser(int rows);
```